# Mi servicio de registro en BD no funciona al subirlo a un servidor

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Al activar este php a través de mi formulario de registro, espero que los datos se suban a la BD, pero solo pasa a la pagina de landing. No hay mensaje de error, y la conexión esta bien realizada porque otros php que dependen de ella funcionan como es debido. Al realizar el sql desde php my admin los datos se añaden con normalidad. 
Por ultimo, el sistema se probo en local, y funcionaba, pero esto es irrelevante, porque ya he probado tantas cambios que el código posiblemente no sea igual que cuando estaba en local.

```
<?php
require 'Conexion.php';

$User=$_POST['User'];
$Correo=$_POST['Correo'];
$Pass=$_POST['Password'];
$Ref=$_POST['referral'];
$Nombre=$_POST['Nombre'];
$Apellido=$_POST['Apellidos'];
$Genero=$_POST['Genero'];
$Pais=$_POST['Pais'];
$Ciudad=$_POST['Ciudad'];
$Direccion=$_POST['Direccion'];
$Direccion2=$_POST['Direccion2'];
$Telefono=$_POST['Telefono'];
$Pregunta=$_POST['Pregunta'];
$Seguridad=$_POST['Seguridad'];

$Insert="INSERT INTO 'user' ('Id_User', 'Name_User', 'Correo', 'Password_User', 'Referente', 'Nombre', 'Apellidos','Genero', 'Pais', 'Ciudad', 'Direccion', 'Direccion2', 'Telefono', 'Pregunta', 'Respuesta') VALUES (NULL,'$User','$Correo','$Pass','$Ref','$Nombre','$Apellido','$Genero','$Pais','$Ciudad','$Direccion','$Direccion2','$Telefono','$Pregunta','$Seguridad')";

$Resultados=mysqli_query($conexion, $Insert);
include "Landing.html";
?>
```

Comment: Que BBDD estas utilizando en el servidor?

Comment: El control de errores es cosa tuya en todo programa que crees. Debes usar un try catch para poder recibir error de esa inserción, de lo contrario no te hará la inserción ni te dará error. Mi recomendación es que concatenes las variables en la variable $insert. Se pueden poner como las tienes, pero en mi experiencia, a veces dan mas problemas que soluciones. Asegúrate de que las columnas de la base de datos no sean de tipo integer, porque tienes entre comillas simples todo, y eso lo convierte a string. Y asegúrate también de que ID_user pueda ser NULL. Nos dices que te da el error del trycatch.

Comment: Puedes establecer un control de errores también evaluando el resultado de la consulta, por ejemplo: `if ($conexion) { require 'Conexion.php';  /*Y todo lo demás ... */ if ( $Resultados=mysqli_query($conexion, $Insert) ) { include "Landing.html"; } else { "Error: ".mysqli_error($conexion); }  } else { echo "No hay conexion"; }` Ahí te dirá lo que ha ocurrido. Tu tarea es controlar el código, de modo que no se quede mudo ante ciertas situaciones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En primer lugar hay demasiadas comillas.Prueba con `$Insert="INSERT INTO user (Id_User, Name_User, Correo, Password_User, Referente, Nombre, Apellidos,Genero, Pais, Ciudad, Direccion, Direccion2, Telefono, Pregunta, Respuesta)` para la primera parte del select.

Y para la segunda te **recomiendo** que leas este [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) (abajo hay ejemplos para que lo puedas implementar fácilmente) para evitar las temible inyecciones sql. También es probable que aunque no este fallando, el insert no funcione debido a los tipos de datos que están llegando al encerrar las variables entre comillas.

Comment: Efectivamente era una combinación de estos dos problemas, junto a un problema longitud de campos y que el campo numérico vacío no se aceptaba como numero. Muchas gracias también por la recomendación para evitar las inyecciones.